# I need to calculate the intersection of an arbitrary line and a vertical or horizontal line

Tags: geometry

Let us say I have a straight line. I also have a graph, 480x360. How could I take this line, and calculate where it intersects the edge of the graph?

The graph's x-axis spans from -240 to 240, the y-axis spans from -180 to 180. (apologies if this isn't clear enough, I'm not the best at explaining)

Comment: How is your line given? What parameters about it are available to you?

Comment: The line has 2 points, of which I can calculate the y intercept and the slope.

Comment: I suggest you update your question so that the above comment is contained in the question. That will help other people understand what you are asking without need to go through comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation for a line is $y = ax + b$, where $a$ and $b$ are constants which determine the precise form of the line in 2D. Then solve the equations:

$y = ax + b$

Such that $x = \pm 240, -180 \leq y \leq 180$. And:

$x = (y - b) / a$

Such that $a \neq 0, y = \pm 180, -240 \leq x \leq 240$

Comment: Thank you! (I had to add more characters to post this)

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you have some sort of equation in $x$ and $y$ defining your line.

Then, to pick one of your edges to start with, the equation of the right edge of your graph is $$x = 240$$ Plug that into your equation and solve for the value of $y$, and let's call that value $y_0$. Then that intersection point is $$(240, y_0)$$

You then do the analogous procedure three more times for the other edges. But note that you'll need to check the range of your answers - most likely only two out of the four intersection points will actually lie within range of your graph.

To get a more specific answer, you'll have to be more specific about what form you have your line in.

Answer (score 0):

Let's just say without loss of generality the equation of the line is ax + by = c. Then to find when it intersects the right edge of the screen, we plug in x = 240 and then we can solve the linear equation to find the point where it intersects the top edge. We can find the other intersections by plugging in x = -240, y = 180, and  y = -180 to see where it intersects the left, upper, and bottom edges, respectively.